# Capturing HTML form, modifying and re-posting with JQuery

Tags: jquery, post

I have a form (HTML) which I'm trying to post to an API I've written in Node.

I need to make some modifications to the posted form elements with JQuery, before submitting.

Currently, I'm capturing when the form is submitted, appending the necessary attributes and then (trying) to re-post it.

I'm able to catch the form, append the necessary attributes, serialize it and display it on the page (which looks right_ - but posting it just returns 'Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at buildParams...'.

I'm still quite new to JQuery, so have probably done something very silly, but am just completely stuck on this.

Has anyone has any ideas / suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Here's the code I'm using

```
  $('#blk-visits').on('submit', function(e){ //captures form submission
      e.preventDefault(); // prevent from from submitting
      var form = this;
         $(form).append(
             $('<input>')
                .attr('type', 'hidden')
                .attr('name', 'store_id')
                .val(rows_selected)
          );

         $.post("http://localhost:3002/campaign/", form, function(result){  // post to local dev server
           console.log(result); // print response from server in console
         });

         $('#test-console').text($(form).serialize());  // print form to page for debug
  });
```

Comment: `var form = new FormData(this);
form.append('store_id',rows_selected);`

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately, this gives me 'Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation'

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post("http://localhost:3002/campaign/", {store_id: rows_selected}, function(result){  // post to local dev server
           console.log(result); // print response from server in console
         });
```

This is enough, don't need to create `form`

**Edit:**
As your comment you want to send the input inside the form also:

```
var data = $(form).serializeArray().reduce(function(m,o){ 
    m[o.name] = o.value;
    return m;
}, {});

data['store_id'] = rows_selected;
$.post("http://localhost:3002/campaign/", data, function(result){  // post to local dev server
           console.log(result); // print response from server in console
         });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response - this does post successfully, but only the 'store_id' is the being posted (I am trying to append store_id onto the previously submitted results. So, I think the problem lies with how I'm appending it, but can't work it out (yet)

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('#blk-visits').on('submit', function(e){ //captures form submission
      e.preventDefault(); // prevent from from submitting
      var form = new FormData(this);
      form.append('store_id',rows_selected);

         $.post("http://localhost:3002/campaign/", form, function(result){  // post to local dev server
           console.log(result); // print response from server in console
         });

         $('#test-console').text($(form).serialize());  // print form to page for debug
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am getting 'Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation' when using this method.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the replies. Managed to get it working with your help. Using serialize was the answer, and was probably staring me in the face all along.

For reference, here is the complete code I used:

```
   $('#blk-visits').on('submit', function(e){ //captures form submission
      e.preventDefault();   // prevent form from submitting
      var form = this;
         $(form).append(
             $('<input>')
                .attr('type', 'hidden')
                .attr('name', 'store_id')
                .val(rows_selected)
         );

         var data = $(form).serializeArray(); //serialize appended form data

         $.post("http://localhost:3002/campaigns/", data, function(result){ //post to api
             $("#console").html(result); //print response from server in console
         });

      $('#test-console').text($(form).serialize()); //print form to page for debug
      $('input[name="store_id"]', form).remove(); //remove added elements
```